# Issue with Python Script

Tags: python, bluetooth, openpyxl, pybluez

I'm having an issue with my code where I get the output of:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "1stHour.py", line 48, in 
>   ws1.cell(column=1, row=i, value="%s" % blue_student_list[i])
>   IndexError: list index out of range`

```
# coding=utf:8
from pythonzenity import Message
from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill
from openpyxl import Workbook
import bluetooth
import time



def student_check(index):
    result = bluetooth.lookup_name(blue_address_list[index], timeout=3)
    if (result is not None):
        return True
    else:
        return False

blue_student_list = ['Name', 'Name2']
blue_address_list = ['Address', 'Address2']


redFill = PatternFill(start_color='FF0000', end_color='FF0000', fill_type='solid')
greenFill = PatternFill(start_color='00FF00', end_color='00FF00', fill_type='solid')


for i in range(0, len(blue_address_list)):

    i = i + 1

    ws1.cell(column=1, row=i, value="%s" % blue_student_list[i])
    if (student_check(i)):
       ws1.cell(column=2, row=i, value="%s" % "Present").fill = greenFill
    else:
       ws1.cell(column=2, row=i, value="%s" % "Absent").fill = redFill


Message(title="Attendance Checker",text="You can now open the Excel Document on your Desktop", timeout=3000)
```

I had this working but forgot to save it, so I don't have the correct way I had it before on here anymore. What can I do to prevent this error? I feel like I'm forgetting something or writing in the `i = i + 1` part on my code.

Comment: you should not do i = i + 1 as i is already incremented by for loop and your blue_student_list does not have len = 3

Comment: I changed it to have a length of 3 but it still isn't working... @SumitKumar

Comment: why do you want to increment value of i there. Is it doing anything specific there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do this:

```
for i in range(0, len(blue_address_list)):
```

there is no need to also do this:

```
i = i + 1
```

And doing so will cause the type of bug you see.

You seem to be doing this since the library you are using uses 1-based indexing rather than 0-based as in Python lists. But you are still using the (1 too high) `i` to index into a list when you do this:

```
blue_student_list[i]
```

So, instead of incrementing `i` a second time, pass a 1-higher value to the things that need it:

```
ws1.cell(column=1, row=i+1, value="%s" % blue_student_list[i])
```

and similarly in the other calls to `ws1.cell`.

This is.. unusual for a Python library, to say the least, and so it probably warrants putting a comment like this just before you first use `row=i+1`:

```
# Need row=i+1 because openPyXML uses 1-based indexing
```

Comment: Same output as from the user above. OpenPyXL says "ValueError: Row or Column values must be at least 1".

Comment: @dylan see my updated answer. It seems that you're trying to work around an oddity in that library, but you need to be careful to index the list with the right value too.

Comment: Turns out I completely forgot to wb.save it as well. This worked and was more effective than the original. Thanks!

Comment: The reason openpyxl uses 1-based indexing is to reduce confusion when switching coordinates systems. There is, however, very little need to use manual counters as my own answer demonstrates.

Answer (score 1):

Rows and columns are 1-indexed in openpyxl so `ws['A1']` corresponds to `ws.cell(column=1, row=1)`.

The `IndexError` is almost certainly coming from the `blue_student_list[i]` lookup. Best using an extra line to get the value and avoid using "%s" formatting as it's completely unnecessary here.

```
for idx, value in enumerate(blue_student_list, start=1):
    ws1.cell(column=1, row=idx, value=value)
```

Comment: So remove the `for i in range(0, len(blue_address_list)): i = i + 1` part and replace it with what you have? Or remove the i = i + 1 part and add your code to the end of `for i in range` part?

Comment: Yes. You seem to be struggling with Python in general.

Comment: +1; +10 if I could. My answer directly solves the immediate problem, but using more Pythonic idioms like `enumerate` makes the code better in general and this probably deserves the accept over mine. One (marginal) improvement might be passing `start` as a keyword argument to `enumerate`, instead of a plain number. @dylan to learn Python idioms like this, you might want to watch Raymond Hettinger's [Transforming Code](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OSGv2VnC0go) video; also consider posting at codereview.SE once it works, there's some more small things you can do that don't fit in comments.